# Why does concurrentHashMap need an array of Segment? Why cant it acquire lock on node?

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I was reading this article to understand how ConcurrentHashMap worked internally: https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java

But I do not understand use of Segments here. It is `public final Segment[] segments = new Segment[32]` in this article.
Before I read this article, my understanding was there would be multiple Entry tables & each segment would hold reference of one array of the multiple. But in this article there is only one

```
 protected transient Entry[] table;
```

My questions are:

1. Will this above single array "**table**" hold entry for all the segments? Meaning, if I put 2 entries in ConcurrentHashMap, which would return 2 different segments, would it still go under same entry table above? I am confused why aren't there multiple arrays for each segment defined above?
2. Instead of using a segment and locking it, when can't a lock be acquired Entry object and perform write/update?

Answer (score 2):

> Will this above single array "table" hold entries for all the segments?

Yes.

> I am confused why aren't there multiple arrays for each segment defined above?

Because, the `Segment` objects really serve as locks for segments of the main `entries` array.   The segments are conceptual "slices" of the main array.

> Instead of using segment and locking it, when cant a lock be acquired Entry object and perform write/update ?

An operation that updates the `ConcurrentHashMap` will typically read and write the main `entries` array.  Simply locking one `Entry` is not sufficient to perform table insertions and deletions safely.

---

If the descriptions in that article are confusing, you could also look at the source code directly; e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java/

Comment: Thanks Stephen. But I am still did not get use of Segments here .What if I used array of String instead of array of segments ? Would it work?

Comment: It could be made to work, more or less.  In the Java 8 implementation, the `Segment` class is a subclass of `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: So ... if the code was changed to use `synchronized` locking rather than `Lock` locking, then you could use a `String`.

Comment: @StephenC I've java 1.8.0.151 on my machine. I went through the source code, and it seems the Segment is not used for synchronization. Instead, lock is acquired directly on 'Node' which is nothing but the Entry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no array of Segments in ConcurrentHashMap since Java 8 and onwards. It directly has an array of `Node<K,V>` as a table.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8 onward** there is no segment array, **lock is acquired on the first node of the LinkedList** of a particular hashed index/bucket of the internal hash table array.

[ConcurrentHashMap internal](http://techmastertutorial.in/java-collection-internal-concurrent-hashmap.html)